# Check for internet connection, and connection type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, connection

I wish to check:

A - Whether there's an internet connection.
B - If there is, whether it's over wifi or not.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)You need to look for the answer before post, this question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this example from apple [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html).

You can then copt `Reachability.h` and `Reachability.m` to your project and use it inside your project.

You can use [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) version from Tony Million that fits for ARC and GDC projects.